# What to do when my boss is very disorganized?

Tags: work-environment

My boss is very disorganized and short tempered.

Some examples:

- I scheduled meetings for him. Let him know beforehand several days. Text him a summary of meetings every morning. He ended up missing them or rescheduling because he came late at work or just simply wanted to meet people from other departments. I spend my days calling people to let them know their meetings being canceled.
- I give him important docs (contracts, docs that need to be sign). When I ask whether he sign it, so that I can return to people. He says he doesn't know and ask me to search for them in his office. (ALWAYS HAPPEN). So whenever I present him something, I wait for him to sign it and take it back immediately.
- He decides according to mood. He gives me a design task. When I go through many changes to meet his expectation. At the last minute, he changes his mind because when he goes to another shop, he prefers their design. So people works are always in "pending" status.
- Be angry at random people. My boss has impossible expectation. When he goes out and observes another shop, he sees something good about them. he goes back and force changes on the departments. But he is a high level manager who only understands the surface and not details of the company structure & system. head of departments explain to him why the changes are not relevant/feasible, but he doesn't accept. he isn't angry at head departments. But when someone else presents him with the unchanged work (e.g an old design that he wanted to change but head department didn't want), he yells at them why its not changed. they say that its not within their responsibilities (its truly not). He ignores it and keep yelling. E.g he wanted to see the retail price list. I presented him the current price list and he started shouting that it was not right. He wanted to change this price list for years but people stopped him because his ideas were not feasible. When I say it was not my job to come up with the price list. He said NO, and started talking about how wrong it was.

It's not that I don't like change. But this crazy changing frequency happens very frequent. Everybody is disappointed. I am a new collage graduate who struggles to find job. I know if I quit, I have no experience to find another job, nowhere to go, and no money. I could go through all of this until I am knowledgeable enough to move on. But every time I go home from work, it felt so wrong. I work 60 hours/ week but get paid 48 hours. The company doesn't pay for overtime work. I stay back because my boss says "you cannot go home earlier than me". His working schedule is from 11a-8p while everybody else is from 8-5 (including me). So I always stay at work from 8a-8p

English is not my 1st langue, so please spare the grammar errors. If someone has suggestions on my situations, it is appreciated.

Comment: is it your job to design things, or to assist your boss on schedules, meetings, and paperwork? Also, why do you come in at 8?

Comment: `I could go through all of this until I am knowledgeable enough to move on` Don't. imho it's not worth it. It may be hard to find another job fast enough, but on the long term, it's much better that several years of that situation.

Comment: I am his assistant. I do what he assigns me to. normal work hour in my country is 8am - 5pm. the boss comes late

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't take it personal.  Sounds like your boss treats other the same way.  Other than you have to say until 8 which is unfair.  He is dependent on you but not sure that is a good thing.

You could go to HR about the hours but with this boss that is likely to go poorly for you.

I am surprised a senior level manager can hold his position acting that way.  If department heads are pushing back that is a sign he may be losing power.  See if you can hold on for a year.  He might get fired in a year or move on.

Comply rather than care. If the contract does not get signed it does not reflect poorly on you.  Present the contract to him. Use big tags for sign here so you can find it easily when he asks for the contract.  Keep a log of documents on his desk for signature.  Not suggesting you sabotage the guy but you don't need to save him from himself either.

Could you use email to notify about cancelled meetings?

Sound like are an assistant to him.  If you know the prior assistant ask them how to best handle you boss.

Try and have a conversation with him about 8-8.  Say something like "Boss, 12 hour days are just wearing me out."  If he gets aggressive then just let it go.

Quit and look for a job is clearly not a good option. But you can look for another job. But do so discretely as this is a person that may fire you if they find out you are looking for another job.

Comment: labor law in my country is not strict. no-one wants to cause troubles with their employers. its a win (employer) / lose (employee) situation. he won't get fired in a year. hes the president. thats why he can do whatever he wants. but because he is too disorganized and cannot keep track of things. his subordinates continue to ignore his commands. and I am his assistant so i usually get all the fire. Maybe I will stay for a year and move on. thank you

Comment: Unless he is the owner even Presidents can get fired.  If the company under performs the board will look at the President.   His actions have to be negatively effecting the overall performance of the company.

Comment: It's actually not a win / lose but a lose / lose situation. Eventually he will get his wishes and company will go down the toilet.

Comment: @gnasher729 President / CEO can get fired unless they own the company.

Answer (score 4):

First the working time. Your boss argues that you cannot leave before him. Let's for arguments sake say that this is a reasonable argument. In that case I cannot see a reason why you should arrive three hours before he arrives. Figure out what start / end time would match your 48 paid hours and the bosses presence and suggest that change.

About the personality problems and the business problems of your boss: They are not your problems. If he makes stupid business decisions, that's not your problem. If he misses meetings that you reminded him of again and again, that's his problem and not yours. If he shouts at you how wrong you are about not changing a price list that shouldn't be changed, you need to understand clearly that there is nothing wrong with what you did. Imagine you are paid to be the nanny for some unruly children. Or you are working in a zoo looking after the chimpanzees that are flinging their **** everywhere. You wouldn't feel bad about the chimpanzee's mess. Well, annoying if you have to clean it up, but it's not personal.

Do *your* job. If he says he wants the price list changed, which you know is not feasible, you ask what changes he wants made, and you change the list. Then watch what happens if he gives the changed list to his department heads and enjoy.

PS. Your English is absolutely fine. There are some things that are not exactly like a native British or American would put them, but everything is perfectly understandable.

Comment: unsure how feasible the first paragraph is, but the rest is good, don't take it personally, just comply

Comment: Should be feasible assuming two facts: The boss does not want Shiro to leave before he leaves. And Shiro is paid to work 48 hours.

Comment: your comment actually makes me laugh. I did the changes he required, and when it was presented in meetings. the changes were turned down by all head departments. I guess it was not the changes that annoyed me, but to continue to work on stuffs that would absolutely be rejected. Like working on things that people will never give a damn about. But yes, its the only way. I would just focus on my job, get experience so that I can move on. Thank you for the thoughtful comment

Comment: @shiro people have whole careers based on doing useless things, half of govt for a start :-)